# django & send_mail in docker leads to SMTPServerDisconnected

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I setup a google email backend for django and all is working fine until i run the whole stuff in docker-compose containers.

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /events/register/4/
please run connect() first
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.99.100:80/events/register/4/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: SMTPServerDisconnected
Exception Value:    
please run connect() first
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py in send, line 359
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.6.2
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/app']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Jul 2017 11:07:45 +0200
```

Any idea what's going wrong here? Why is it disconnecting in a container?

Comment: post your view which is being used by the url /events/register/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out:
In the docker-compose.yml i have something like this:

```
env_file:
  - ".env"
```

The content of the .env was:

```
key = value
```

This runs great on a local machine loading the .env file first.
However docker needs a more strict format:

```
key=value
```

**No spaces!!**

The error was that my EMAIL_* settings wasn't set correctly with spaced key/value pairs